# jquery button enable and disable based on data retrieved from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have a button with drop down list, i want the button to be enabled only for one cert type. I am getting the cert type from DB and using below code. The button i want to enable and disable is the "Action" button. I have the cert type fetched and listed in the table as (${cert.certType}). How could i used that field to enable and disable the function. Could anyone help? Thanks.

code Snippet:

```
<c:forEach var="cert" items="${certificates}" varStatus="status">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><c:out value="${status.count}" /></td>
                                        <td>${cert.commonName}</td>
                                        <td>${cert.validFrom}</td>
                                        <td>${cert.validTo}</td>
                                        <td>${cert.generatedDate}</td>
                                        <td>${cert.certType}</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle ${cert.certType}"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                Actions <span class="caret"></span>
                                            </button>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    <li><a data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#editCertModal" data-id="${cert.id}">Edit Cert</a></li>

                                                    <li><a data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#deleteCertModal_${cert.id}">Delete Cert</a></li>

                                                    <li><a data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#renewCertModal" id="${cert.id}">Renew Cert</a></li>
                                                    <li><a title="Downloads the cert in .pem file" 
                                                   href="/DownloadPemFile/${cert.id}">Download</a></li>
                                                    <li><a 
                                                    onclick="alert('To be implemented.');">View EventLog</a></li>

                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS file i used below:-

$(function(){ $('.IssuerCert').prop('disabled', true); });

Comment: I'm not sure this will work. Even a `disabled` attribute set to `false` will still render the button as disabled. https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_disabled

Comment: Thanks for the comment but when i add that attribute it disabled all

Comment: Good point! @JoelCDoyle

Perhaps: `<button ${cert.certType === '<TYPE OF CERT HERE>' ? 'disabled' : null}` >`

Comment: <button type="button"
             class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
             data-toggle="dropdown" ${cert.certType} === 'Issuer Certificate' ? 'disabled': null>
             Actions <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>

Comment: @liz The close of the curved bracket should be after null

Comment: Please look at the updated code on the above jsp for the button "Action" and then i used below code in my JS file and it worked. Thanks all for the help

Comment: $(function(){
 $('.IssuerCert').prop('disabled', true);
 
});

Comment: this disabled the button for the type of cert i specified.